# Main difference between the two different types of VPC links in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

What is the difference between a `VPC Link for REST APIs` and a `VPC Link for HTTP APIs`. In general I don't really understand the nuisance differences between a `REST` and a `HTTP` API as one refers to a style of API as opposed to `GraphQL` or `SOAP` which use the `HTTP` protocol and the other refers to the protocol used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general differences between HTTP and REST API are listed in [Choosing between HTTP APIs and REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html). The key thing to know about HTTP API is that it is meant to be much cheaper and easier to use then REST API, but at the same time is much less feature reach than REST.

Regarding VPC links, they also differ in the way they work. The link for REST API can be visualized as follows:

```
REST API --> VPC link --> NLB
```

The HTTP API is more versatile and more flexible:

```
                                 /--> NLB        
HTTP API --> VPC link --> NIC --|---> ALB
                                 \--> AWS Cloud Map
```

The [NIC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) created for the link for HTTP API is visible in your account. Also since it is a NIC, you can associated security group with it and control access to other services through the security group rules. This can't be done in REST API, since NLB does not have security group.